# SSL implimentation in old Qt version 4.2.3

Tags: ssl, qt4

Greeting ,
I am enable to find out any method to implement SSL services with Qt 4.2.3 version .I am presently restricted to use 4.2.3 version , can't use 4.3 or later version . Please suggest me any way to come out from this problem .

Comment: Maybe it's time for your organization to upgrade to newer Qt. Analyze the costs and benefits of migrating vs. staying at 4.2.3 whenever your see some feature that's not available in 4.2.3.

Answer (score 0):

There is a LGPLv2.1 licensed Qt add-on named [QCA - Qt Cryptography Architecture](http://delta.affinix.com/qca/). It supports SSL and TLS and other crypto-related technologies. It depends on Qt 4.2+ and is cross-platform in a typical Qt way.